# PHP 複数条件の検索について

Tags: php, mysql

こんにちは。現在PHPを独学で学習しています。
現在、データベースにある情報を複数の条件で検索したいのですが、検索結果が表示されません。

具体的に、htmlは表示されますが、検索結果（データベースに入っている情報）が表示されません。

表示されないのは何故なのか、もしお分かりの方がいましたら、ご教授ください。

1. SQLが発行できていない
2. データベースに接続できていない。
3. その他

もしくは、現在のコードをベースに、複数検索できるコードがありましたら、教えて頂けますでしょうか。

**現在のコード**

```php
<form method="post" action="searchtest.php">
<div class="studentinfo">

<p>顧客番号：   <input type="text" name="id"></p>
<p>担当者：     <input type="text" name="Staff_Name"></p>
<p>ステータス： <input type="text" name="Status"></p>
</div>

<div class="Schoolinfo">
<p>名前：          <input type="text" name="Name"></p>
<p>キャンパス：    <input type="text" name="Campus" ></p>
<p>コース開始日：  <input type="date" name="Start_Date" ></p>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="検索する">
</form>
```

**searchtest.php**

```php
<?php

$search    =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'search');
$id        =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id');
$Staff_Name=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Staff_Name');
$Status    =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Status');
$Name      =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Name');
$Campus    =filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Campus');
$Start_Date=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Start_Date');

if(!is_null($search)){
  $sql ="SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE 1 ";
  $data=[];

  if(!is_null($id)){
    $sql.="AND id=? ";
    $data[]=$id;
  }
  if(!is_null($Staff_Name)){
    $sql.="AND Staff_Name LIKE ? ";
    $data[]="%".$Staff_Name."%";
  }
  if(!is_null($Status)){
    $sql.="AND Status=? ";
    $data[]=$Status;
  }
  if(!is_null($Campus)){
    $sql.="AND Campus LIKE ? ";
    $data[]="%".$Campus."%";
  }
  if(!is_null($Name)){
    $sql.="AND Name LIKE ? ";
    $data[]="%".$Name."%";
  }
  if(!is_null($Start_Date)){
    $sql.="AND Start_Date=? ";
    $data[]=$Start_Date;
  }
  if(count($data)==0) $sql.="AND 0 ";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($data);
}
?>
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: プログラムを見るとエラーを取得していないようですがエラーを取得してみるとどのような結果になりますか？https://www.php.net/manual/ja/class.pdostatement.php

Answer (score 0):

SQLクエリを投げる前に**予めDBに接続する必要**がありますが、提示されたコード内にはDBに関する情報が何もありませんので、まずは正しい手順を確認してください。

---

PDOインスタンスの作成例

```
// $dns = 'mysqld:dbname=データベース名;host=ホスト名';
// dns(Database Source Name)
$dns = 'mysqld:dbname=myapp;host=localhost';
$usre = 'root';
$password = '';
$con = new PDO($dns, $user, $password);

// DBとの接続を行ったあとでクエリを実行する

$con->prepare('SQL文');
```

参考：
[【PHP・PDO】データベースに接続する方法](https://se-tomo.com/2018/12/26/%E3%80%90php%E3%83%BBpdo%E3%80%91%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/)

Comment: cubickさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。

記載が不足しており申し訳ありません。
データベースの接続はこちらには載せていませんが、最初に接続をしております。

SQL文が発行されていない、もしくは別の原因が考えられるようでしたら教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->execute($data);
```

でexecuteした後、何もしてないですね。

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // ここでresultに1列のデータが取れます
}
```

のように、データを受け取りましょう。

ただ、最近はRDB周りはフレームワークで専用のモジュールを使うので、
実務だとあまりPDOStatement自体使わないと思います。

また、このような質問がstackoverflowに上がることに疑問があります。
教材はちゃんとしたものを使っていますか？見直したほうがいい気がします。
Webで勉強できるからと思わず、ちゃんと本なりprogate使ったりしたほうが効率がいいですよ。

ちゃんとした教材であれば

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($selectQuery);
$stmt->execute($data);
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
}
```

はセットで出てくるはずです。